# Import process running much slower when started inside timer job

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-form, timer-jobs, performance, import

We have implemented a CSV import fort some large CSV files. The process can be triggered by the user changing a drop down value of a file inside a sharepoint library to "pending". Our importer then sees that and starts importing the file, which takes around 1 hour.

Now we have implemented an automatic import by a daily timer job. The timerjob also simply set's the pending flag to trigger the import. When done this way, the import job runs for around 5 hours - 5 times longer!

I have searched why this could be the case, but found no clue. Somehow I suppose the import now must be running under some other context (timerjob context?) which has maybe lower priority and thus takes much longer.

Otherwise the import result is the same and import finishes successful.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you gather performance counters (CPU, Memory) during the import, maybe server on which timer job is being executed, is running out of memory? Another hint, did you check how many instances of this timer job is actually running on your farm, if incorrectly "installed" it could be executed on multiple servers at the same time?

Comment: I don't have access to the server directly, but I doubt that is an issue, because every manual run runs faster and every automatic run runs slow. With a hardware issue it would behave the same in both cases. Also the job is configured to run explicitly only on one of the two servers of the farm. I migrated the whole solution once to my development machine and also could reproduce the same behaviour. Manual import was fast and automatic (timer job import) was slow - on the same machine.